# Lubavitch Kinnos

Tags: minhag, chabad, tisha-bav

Kehot does not sell a book of Kinnos for Tisha B'Av, and so this led me to assume there was no particular nusach that Lubavitchers use for kinnos. If that is so, what nusach is used? Nusach Ashkenaz? Some random Nusach Sfard version? I have not attended a Chabad house on Tisha B'Av so I really don't know what publication's generally used.

Comment: Is there any difference between ashkenaz and sefard (Chassidic) on this?

Comment: Am I inferring correctly that Kehot is specifically a Lubavitch publication?

Comment: @DanF - Yes, it _only_ sells siddurim and such according to the Chabad nusach. The publishing house was established by R. Yosef Yitzchak Schneerson when he came to America specifically to print Lubavitch seforim for the flourishing Chasidic dynasty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This article](http://www.shturem.net/index.php?section=news&id=81585) describing a publication of the prayers and laws for the entire Tisha B'Av according to the Chabad practice says:

> הקינות נערכו על פי הנהוג בקהילות חב"ד, על פי נוסח האשכנזים

The Kinos are ordered according to what is customary in Chabad communities, [i.e.] according to the Nusach of Ashkenazim.

To the best of my knowledge, Chabad does not have a specific Nusach developed for Kinos, or any specific changes to Kinos. They do not say the additional ones printed in some versions that mention The Holocaust.

Comment: I know a few Lubavitchers that use *Eskhol/Shai LaMorah*'s *Kinnos*, and the davening is Sefard

Comment: So "nusach ha'Ashkenazim" means Nusach Ashkenaz, right? Or does it mean the nusach of the Ashkenazi Hasidim, namely, Nusach Sfard... Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @ezra Askenaz, yes.

Comment: @ploni, I've never noticed a difference between what chabad is using and the Koren Kinos. Of course, the non Kinos parts are going to follow nusach ari.

Comment: Is there any difference between ashkenaz and sefard (Chassidic) WRT kinnos?

Comment: @Ploni see https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/86232/11501