# Are there different nusachos for the kinnos?

Tags: nuschaot, tisha-bav

Follow up to [my previous question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/83625/lubavitch-kinnos) about Lubavitch kinnos.

I often see kinnos books labeled "Ashkenaz," "Sfard," etc. but are there really differences between the kinnos or are these labels referring to the davening often included in the books?

Additionally, and similarly, are there any differences between Sefardi kinnos and Ashkenazi kinnos? I would assume there are because there are almost *always* differences between the two kehillos.

Comment: No source, but the kinnot do differ between Ashkenazim and Sephardim. Ashkenazim have more kinnot about the Rishonic period, with such subjects as Gezeirot ק"ט, Rindsfleisch Massacres, et c. I am unaware of the content of Sephardi kinnot, but the "Ashkenaz" vs. "Sfard" is simply the nusach of the other tefillot.

Comment: By `Sfard` do you mean Chassidic Sfard or real Sfard? Please edit to clarify.

Comment: @Ploni - By `Sfard` I obviously mean the Chasidic nusach. You would say Edot HaMizrach or Nusach Sefardi to mean the nusach of the Sephardic Jews. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nusach_Sefard).

Comment: not likely. the difference are probably in regards to other prayers in the books besides the kinos themselves such as kaddish

Answer (score 2):

Regarding *nusach* Ashkenaz and Sfard, the preface to artscroll's kinot says explicitly

> Although **the kinot are standard in both nusach Ashkenaz and nusach
>   Sfard**, there are minor variations among the texts. Some of these are
>   obviously the work of Christian censors, who removed or altered
>   stanzas, phrases or words they found offensive [...] We emphasize,
>   however, that the variations are relatively few.

The Sefardi (*Edot HaMizrach*) kinnot are very different, partly because the two communities' history of persecutions differs so significantly. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinnot) has a list of the Sefardi kinnot and there is no overlap I could see with the Ashkenazi ones. The evening service is also much longer.

Comment: This is only two subsets of Ashkenazi practice...

Comment: @DoubleAA you are absolutely right - I am not sure why I stopped halfway in my first answer